# Conditional statements with MDCheckbox

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to check whether the checkbox state is down/normal(True/False) and execute further codes

I tried

```
if self.root.ids.chk_box.active==True:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

But it doesn't work properly

Edit:
Full code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.factory import Factory 
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox 

Root="""
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

<Obj_1@BoxLayout>:
    MDCheckbox:
        id:chk_box
        
BoxLayout:
    id:Layout_1 
    
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"Add"
        on_press:root.add_widget(F.Obj_1()) 

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"print state" 
        on_press:app.State()
    

"""

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Root)
    

    def State(self):
        self.Obj_1=Factory.Obj_1()
        if self.Obj_1.ids.chk_box.active==True:
            print('True')
        else:
            print("False")
        
Main().run()
```

In the above code, Add button adds the checkbox into the main Layout and then there is a Button 'print state' to know the state

You can clearly see that it is printing False all the time even if the Checkbox state is True

The same thing works fine if the MDCheckbox was not placed inside a Factory object

Note: this is to know the state of the checkbox and I'm definitely aware of the `on_active:` function, but I can't use that

Comment: Pleas post a [mcve].

Comment: Updated it with full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems with your code:

- In your `State()` method, the code `self.Obj_1=Factory.Obj_1()` is creating a new instance of `Obj_1`. That new instance has no relationship to the instance that appears in your GUI, so checking its state is of no use.
- Also in your `State()` method, the code: `if self.Obj_1.ids.chk_box==True:` is not checking the `state` (or the `active` property) of the `MDCheckBox`.
- The code in the `kv`: `on_press:root.add_widget(F.Obj_1())` creates a new instance of `Obj_1`, but does not keep a reference to that instance. That makes it difficult to access the `Obj_1` instance to check its `state`.

Here is a modified version of your code that addresses the above issues:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Root = """
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

<Obj_1@BoxLayout>:
    MDCheckbox:
        id:chk_box

BoxLayout:
    id:Layout_1 

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"Add"
        # on_press:root.add_widget(F.Obj_1()) 
        on_press: app.add_Obj()  # call a method of the App, rather than creating the Obj_1 instance here

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"print state" 
        on_press:app.State()
"""


class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Root)

    def add_Obj(self):
        # create a new instance of `Obj_1` and save a reference to it
        self.Obj_1 = Factory.Obj_1()
        self.root.add_widget(self.Obj_1)

    def State(self):
        # self.Obj_1 = Factory.Obj_1()
        if self.Obj_1.ids.chk_box.active == True:  # Check the `active` property of the `Obj_1` instance
            print('True')
        else:
            print("False")


Main().run()
```